# Sencha touch 2: app hangs-up after creating all-classes build/ minifying the source

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I build my sencha app using 'sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3' & build it using 'sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d ./lib/sdk'. Initially all-classes.js was empty after every build. Now I am successful in creating all-classes.js. I got the all-classes running after I switched to SDK tools version 1.2.3 from version2.0.0. But when I run my app by including all-classes, my app hangs and nothing works further. It simply loads the first screen and nothing else works, no scrolling, no tap events are fired. 
The app simply hangs-up.

I fired alert messages in my application launch method to verify if the app is getting launched and the alert is working fine. Also I tried adding an alert in the initialize method of my first view that I add to the viewport, which fires.

Unable to fix it. Its urgent for me to fix it!
Does anyone know how to handle this behavior?

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building it with sencha `app build -e production -a archive`